# Rename pdf files recursively if their names begin with a year

Tags: macos, pdf, rename

Problems similar to mine were asked about and answered (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935127/rename-files-recursively-mac-osx)). This is a bit more specific:

I have a lot of pdf files in many dedicated folders and only some of them have their name like this `YEAR_Author(s)Name(s).pdf` (e.g., **2011_Smith.pdf**, **2011_SmithWesson.pdf**), others are named like this `Author(s)Name(s)2011.pdf` (e.g., **Smith2011.pdf**, **SmithWesson2011.pdf**). The latter is my preferred name format. I would like to rename all my files to that format. Following the previous example:

```
2011_Smith.pdf -> Smith2011.pdf
2011_SmithWesson.pdf -> SmithWesson2011.pdf
```

Is there a way to change such filenames recursively (and smartly). Do you need to brew rename to be able to do that? I am on macOS.

Comment: Your question is not very clear... some of your files are named `YEAR_AuthorName.pdf` - how are the others named? You would prefer `AuthorName_YEAR.pdf` or `AuthorNameYEAR.pdf` - given that you're asking, just say which you want. Maybe add an example too. And yes, the `rename` from `homebrew` is ideal, a.k.a. Perl `rename`

Comment: I've done 100+ answers on that if you want to look through them https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2836621%20rename

Comment: What part of this involves recursion? I don't see it.

Comment: Hi @Alexander, There is a whole hierarchy of folders, on specific topics etc. Does this make sense?

Comment: It wasn't clear from the question, but yes, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I had a few moments to have a think about this and tried to do it using the rusty old tools that Apple ships (`bash` v3.3, `sed` the ancient, and antiquated `find`) rather than introducing new dependencies.

Let's do this incrementally:

- find the files
- iterate over them
- work out the changes
- check the changes and make them

First thing is to identify your files. I think the following should find all PDFs that start with 4 digits followed by an underscore:

```
find /Users/YOURUSER  -iregex ".*/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_.*\.pdf" 2> /dev/null
```

If that's correct, let's pipe it into a `while` loop and check that looks correct:

```
find /Users/YOURUSER  -iregex ".*/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_.*\.pdf" -print0 2> /dev/null | 
   while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' path; do
      print "$path"
   done
```

Now see if we can twiddle your year off the front and onto the back:

```
#!/bin/bash

find /Users/YOURUSER  -iregex ".*/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_.*\.pdf" -print0 2> /dev/null | 
   while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' path; do
      d=$(dirname  "$path")
      f=$(basename "$path")
      # Strip trailing PDF extension case insensitively and swap 4-digit year followed by underscore, space or dash, from front to back
      f=$(echo "$f" | sed -E 's/\.pdf$//i; s/^([0-9]{4})[_ -](.*)/\2\1/')
      new="${d}/${f}.pdf"
      echo "$path becomes"
      echo "-> $new"
      # mv "$path" "$new"
   done
```

If that all looks good with your files on your system, make a TimeMachine backup first, then uncomment the penultimate line by removing the `#` at the start and run again.

In case you are unfamiliar with `sed`, `\1` refers to whatever was captured in the first set of `(...)` on the left side of the substitution and `\2` refers to whatever was captured in the second set of `(...)` - they are *"capture groups"*.